# How can I prove this function is one-to-one and onto?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph.  Let $V$ be the set of vertices in $G$, and let $P =\{\{a,b\} \mid a,b \in V, a\neq b\}$ be the set of all unordered pairs of vertices.  Let $E$ be the set of all edges in $G$.  Define a function $f\colon E \to P$ as follows:  If $e \in E$ is an edge in $G$, then $f(e) = \{a,b\}$, where $a$ and $b$ are the vertices incident with $e$.

1. Is $f$ one-to-one? Prove or disprove.

I think this proof should start off with $f(a) = f(b)$ for a function to be one-to-one. I'm not sure where to go from here. Is there a characteristic of the graph that I can use?

2. Does $f$ map $E$ onto $P$? Prove or disprove.
   So I have to check if the $\mathrm{im}(f) = P$.  This is false since some points are not included in $P$ that are in the $\mathrm{im}(f)$.  How can I set this up correctly?

Comment: How do you define an edge?

Comment: Remind me of what a simple graph is.  Do every pair of vertices require an edge between them?  Does each pair of vertices have at most one edge between them?  I assume every edge is between two vertices.  Using those definitions it should be explicit whether f is 1-1 or onto.

Comment: Notice it is the SET of all unordered pairs.  so it is not f(e) = (a,b).  It is f(e) = {a,b}.

Comment: The issue here is the definition of edge. For a simple graph, edges are a subset of the collection of 2 element subsets of $V$.

Comment: Are edges in this context directed or not?

Comment: @MorganRodgers: Well, most definitions of simple graphs that I have seen define edges as I wrote above (Chartrang & Zhang p.2, Gould p.3, Diestel p.3, etc.). Clearly one can work with bijections of the 2 element subsets of $V$, in which case a definition connecting an abstract edge with some subsets of $V$ must be produced. This, I believe, is the central issue here.

Comment: According to this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html the edges are undirected, there are no multiple edges but the graph need not be complete (nor connected).  I'm going to go out on a limb and claim on a simple graph the function is 1-1 (because there are no multiple edges) but not onto (as not every pair of vertices define an edge).

Comment: @fleablood: No limb needed :-).

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is onto $\iff$ every pair of vertices has an edge between them. (i.e.  for every (a,b) there is an edge e, so $f(e) = {a,b})

This need not be the case for a simple graph which may have vertices that are not neighbors with every other vertex.

$f$ is one-to-one $\iff$ every pair of vertices has at most one edge between them.  (i.e.  If for every pair of vertices (a,b) have only one edge, e, between them, then f(g) = {a,b} means g = e.)

This is the case with a simple graph which does not allow any multiple edges between vertices nor single loop edges with a single vertex.

So this function need not be onto (although it isn't prohibited) and it must be one-to-one.

Comment: I don't believe f is onto.  If the graph has a vertice with a degree of zero it is not connected to all of it's neighbors, but is contained in P, because P is the set of all unordered pairs of vertices.

Comment: I see that.  I think that's why there's a problem.  The graph is not defined as complete or incomplete.  It is just a graph with edges.  It has to be proved for any simple graph.  @morgan

Comment: Note I never stated whether for any particular graph this function is onto or one-to-one; just the how the conditions of the graph determine the character of the function. If a simple graph has pairs of vertices without edges between them, the function will not be onto.  If it's possible to have more then one edge to a pair of vertices the function will not be 1-1.  However, the characteristics of the function are directly equivalent to the characteristics of the graph.

Comment: According to this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html the edges are undirected, there are no multiple edges but the graph need not be complete (nor connected).  I'm going to go out on a limb and claim on a simple graph the function is 1-1 (because there are no multiple edges) but not onto (as not every pair of vertices define an edge).

Comment: The illustration of a simple graph given has 4 vertices (I'll call them a,b,c,d) and 4 edges.  (A = ab), (B= bc), (C= bd), and (D= cd).  The function isn't onto as there is no f(e) = {a,c} or {a, d}.  It is 1-1 because there are no multiple edges and simple graphs can't have them.

Comment: I should have said "not necessarily onto".  If the graph is complete it is onto but there is no reason to believe the graph is complete.  So in general a graph won't be complete (although it could be).